# Is any purpose served by a Rust function consisting solely of a block of unsafe code?

Tags: rust

The code is copied from [Listing 19-10 of *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#accessing-or-modifying-a-mutable-static-variable). It's meant to illustrate the use of mutable static variables, but that's not my concern here.  Even though this may be fairly labelled as a "toy example", in a book introducing Rust, it raises what I think are serious issues.

All of the code of `add_to_count` is in an `unsafe` block.  What good does this do, as opposed to making the function itself `unsafe`? As is, the signature of the function gives no clue that it is - in essence if not in Rust parlance - unsafe. I wonder why the compiler even allows this. The "benefit" is that, as can be seen below, the function can be called outside of an `unsafe` block.  Why would an introductory text on Rust show how to circumvent a safe programming practice?

```
static mut COUNTER: u32 = 0;

fn add_to_count(inc: u32) {
    unsafe {
        COUNTER += inc;
    }
}

fn main() {
    add_to_count(3);

    unsafe {
        println!("COUNTER: {}", COUNTER);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If a function is marked as `unsafe` it means that the caller is responsible for upholding some number of conditions, otherwise undefined behavior may be introduced.

If a function is *not* marked as `unsafe` but contains unsafe code, then it means that the function is guaranteeing that no choice of parameters will cause unsafe behavior. In practice this often means the function will check some conditions and panic if the conditions aren't met.

By not marking the function as `unsafe` in your example, the author is asserting that nothing can go wrong by mutating a `static mut u32` by some caller-defined amount.

Comment: The OP appears to be conflating two questions. The one they've asked in the title (and that you've answered well) and the implicit "is *this* code a correct use of `unsafe`". It'd be good if you'd touch on that specific aspect as well.

Comment: Maybe also address OPs feelings around "why the compiler even allows this" and "circumvent a safe programming practice".

Comment: I actually omitted discussion of whether good practice is followed here mostly because I don't know much about if `static mut` stuff ever goes unsafe for P.O.D. copy types. Best practice would probably be to leave some sort of `// safety: ...` comment in the function...

Comment: @Shepmaster if you wanna add that stuff, you're probably the person for the job. I can community-wiki my answer.

Comment: No reason to wiki — I might add a sentence or two later on (and you can edit it further / rollback) or I might add a separate answer if it's a lot of content. Your answer addresses the primary question posed by the OP, the rest is all bonus.

Comment: https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2585-unsafe-block-in-unsafe-fn.html might also be relevant to mention.